# What happened to the Atreides family's holdings after the death of Duke Leto?

Tags: dune

What happened to the holdings of the Atreides family after Duke Leto is assassinated?

His family rules planet Caladan, has a seat in the Landsraad assembly of noble families, has control over planet Arrakis, and owns a large stake in the Combine Honnete Ober Advancer Mercantiles (CHOAM). The CHOAM organization controls much of the economic affairs across the galaxy.

An [answer to this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/251811/who-took-over-the-planet-caladan-after-house-atreides-left-for-dune) says what happened to Caladan, but does not say what happened to the rest of House Atreides vast wealth.

> After the Atreides moved to Arrakis, [Count Hasimir Fenring](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Hasimir_Fenring) was named Siridar-Absentia of Caladan. However, when House Atreides ascended to the Golden Lion Throne in 10193 AG following the Arrakis Revolt, Caladan once again came under the direct rule of the Atreides.

And control over Arrakis was returned to House Harkonnen.

But what happened to the rest of the family holdings?

Was their seat in the Landsraad given to another house? Would that seat be abolished?

And who would inherit the family's other economic assets?

Comment: The Landsraad in all likelihood was simply one seat less, unless a new House was made noble, or a minor house became a great house.  It’s membership was based on who was noble, not number of words or any sort of strict number as far as I can tell.  Anything else that could be ‘inherited’ likely went to the Harkonnens as they won the ‘War of Assassins’ between House Atreides and Harkonnen.

Comment: It may have a link with the ducal ring. The Baron wanted to get it, but it was transferred to Paul by Dr. Yueh. Since Paul is still alive, with the ducal ring, everything should be his.

Comment: @suchiuomizu surely the Atreides seat is replaced by a new Corrino seat? Or they both already had seats, and now Paul gets the fancy one on the end.

Comment: Everything should be inherited by Paul and his heirs.

Comment: @OrangeDog Legally speaking it rightfully belonged to Paul, but as far as anyone who might have been making these decisions knew, Paul was dead and House Atreides was extinct.  By the time they realized Paul was alive, Paul was about to give himself a big promotion.